# Pass Array to Asp webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have array need to pass that array to my ASP.Net Webservice

My array looks like this:

```
{
    "lists" [
        {"F0":"LpSeries", "F1":"Description"},
        {"F0":"Second","F1":"StringValue"}
    ]
}
```

I use javascript like this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: jsonText,
    url: "LPService.asmx/GetDataTableFromArray",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

In webservice i have writen like this

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "")]
public DataTable X(RootObject root)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    return dt;
    // do something with your root objects or its child objects...

    //return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

Here I have created a class for root object it looks like this

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string F0 { get; set; }
    public string F1 { get; set; }
    public string F2 { get; set; }
    public string F3 { get; set; }
    public string F4 { get; set; }
    public string F5 { get; set; }
    public string F6 { get; set; }
    public string F7 { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to get the values. Please help me how to resolve this

Comment: In future questions, please take care to format your code correctly. It makes it much easier for others to quickly read and understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way:

```
var myArray1 = new Array();    
var myArray2 = new Array();    
data: "{'myArray1':"+JSON.stringify(myArray1)+",'myArray2':"+JSON.stringify(myArray2)+"}",
```

In your webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SavePage(List<string> myArray1, List<string> myArray2)
{
return myArray1;
}
```